# python function and class

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Question 1:** Write a function called ‘Marquee’ which takes a string, and capitalizes the first letter of every word. 
**Question 2:** Write a class which accomplishes the same actions in Question 2.
I am new to this. it would greatly appreciated if someone can guide me through this.

This is what I so far

```
def Marquee (str.capitalize())
    str="this is string example!"
print str.capitalize()
```

Comment: You really need to go back to your tutor and ask how to do this and learn from the begining, this isn't even python

Comment: We're all a friendly bunch here, but 1) this question reads just like you've told us what you're expected to do, and *expect us* (the community to do it for you) and we don't respond well to that, 2) it shows no effort on your part - even just a more humble, "I did *this* and it came up with *this* and I don't know why!" is better than this..., 3) ummm, well, it's one of the most interesting pieces of attempted Python code I've seen :), and 4) if I take the question literally, yes, I can do question 1 and 2, in fact, can do them in several ways, but that doesn't help you in the least

Comment: I didn't want you to do it for me. I wanted your help as in guide me. If i was doing right or not. Or give me a lead so i can develop it on my own. But thanks for you help anyways!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, that's a start . . .

For example, if we work with one word, say . . .

```
word1 = "this"
```

so you know that calling word1.capitalize(), you get . . .

```
This
```

that's how you would do it for one word, now you have to apply it to a sentence.  the way to do that is you'd have to break up the sentence perhaps using a split function based on space like

```
str.split(" ")
```

which will return a list of words. loop through the list and create a new string to concatenate the words to together into a new sentence. for example can you predict the output of this code?

```
word1 = "this"
word2 = "is"
word3 = "string"
sentence = (word1.capitalize()+ " " + word2.capitalize() + " " + word3.capitalize())
print sentence
```

i dont know any python but im guessing it may look something like this . . .

```
newSentence = ""
for word in str.split(" ")
    newSentence += (word.capitalized() + " ")
print newSentence
```

now we have to place it inside a function to allow us to input any sentence and get the capitalized version of it.  so we need to know how to define a function . . . here's the basic idea, we begin by declaring one using *def* followed by the *name* of the function and then the *paramter*: **def name (paramters)**. if we have no parameters we leave it blank with paranthese **def name ()**. we end the function definition by saying return. it would look like this . . .

```
def Marquee(str):
. . . .
Insert python code to capitalize beginning of every word.
. . . .
return
```

str is the input that the user calls so if i said

```
aSentence = "this is string example"
print Marquee(aSentence)
```

i am supposed to get

```
This Is String Example
```

can you figure out the rest?

Comment: Hey thanks alot appreciate the help.

Comment: oh i forgot you need to add the spaces inbetween each word . . . i hope that should be obvious . . .

Comment: that didn't work.
def Marquee (str.capitalize()) something is wrong with that. I'm trying to figure out a to write it in a different format with out using the the word capitalize

Comment: ok i tried explaining the structure of a function see if that helps

Comment: You're missing the colons, but otherwise, not bad for someone who doesn't know any Python.

Comment: Also, you should avoid naming a variable `str`, because that's the name of the built-in string type. And you define `aSentence` but then pass `a` near the end. But otherwise, this is 99% of the way to a valid, runnable program.

Comment: thanks for the catch i was just trying to help the guy

Comment: @rbtLong: As I said, I'm impressed that there's only three minor and easily fixable problems in an answer from someone who doesn't even know the language.

Answer (score 1):

```
def Marquee (the_string):
    return the_string.title()
```

You call the function like this

```
>>> Marquee("this is string example!")
'This Is String Example!'
```

not sure what is being asked by Question 2, perhaps they want you to subclass str

```
class Question2(str):
    marquee = str.title

print(Question2("this is string example!").marquee())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Marquee = str.title
```

Or, for backward compatibility with old versions of Python:

```
import string
Marquee = string.capwords
```

For a class which does the same thing:

```
class Mar:
    quee = str.title
Marquee = Mar.quee
```

Or, marginally more seriously:

```
class MarqueeClass(object):
    def __call__(self, s):
        return s.title()
Marquee = MarqueeClass()
```

Actually, I notice that question 2 is actually:

> Question 2: Write a class which accomplishes the same actions in Question 2.

This is a circular definition, or possibly a recursive definition with no base case. One way to interpret this is that *anything* is allowable. But I think a stricter interpretation would be that any attempt to even instantiate the class causes infinite recursion:

```
class MarqueeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__init__()
```

On the other hand, it's also possible that 'Question 2' is some context to accomplish the actions in. Although that's not a valid identifier name, you can still look it up indirectly. For example:

```
context = globals()['Question 2']
with context:
    Marquee = str.title
```

I'd also add a note reminding the teacher that `Marquee` is not a good function name according to PEP 8, to make sure the teacher knows you're a smartass and he's a dumbass. :)

Comment: Teacher is a dumbass for sure. Probably ported the lesson from when they were teaching some other language.

Comment: @gnibbler would Marquee be a good function name in any language?

Comment: @DrewV, I wasn't referring to the function name, but it's behaviour - since there is a str method that already does exactly that. PEP 8 just suggests that the function name should be all lowercase. ie. `marquee`

Comment: @abarnert, I don't get part two. Could you possibly explain it again!? thanks

Comment: @DrewV: `Marquee` is the name of my Visual JScript function that outputs the text in `<MARQUEE>` tags for display in IE3. :)

Comment: @gnibbler what is the way to do part two? I am totally lost! Sorry i know this forum isn't used for this. But I have no better way for now

Comment: @user1742146: What is part two? Even assuming the circularity is a mistake and it's supposed to be "Write a class which accomplishes the same actions as in Question 1", that's a ridiculous way to describe a class. Does he want a class that acts like a callable? A class whose instances act like callables? A subclass of `str` that has this extra method? A class that can be constructed from `str` objects and has a special "get-marquee-ified-version" method?

Comment: My professor wants the subclass of str that has the extra method. and construct a class from str